# Populating @select dropdownlist in java

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play framework 2.0.4

In my java file,

```
return ok(views.html.name.render(Name.all(),NameForm));
```

In my html file,

```
@(name: List[Name],NameForm: Form[Name])
```

I want to make a dropdownlist (like using select, option tags in plain HTML)by on data from name array by using @select in @import helper._

I'm quite new to Play thus can someone show me how can I archive this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Examine https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database/ - check in the `editForm` view and `computer` model how to prepare and use options (`Map<String, String>`), most probably it will be better then using List

Comment: And BTW I still don't understand your question, I hope that suggest will help you to find what you need

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it is by defining your options as a list, returned by a static method

Create a Java class

```
public class ComboboxOpts {
    public static List<String> myCustomOptions(){
        List<String> tmp = new ArrayList();

        tmp.add("This is option 1");
        tmp.add("This is option 2");
        tmp.add("This is option 3");
        return tmp;
    }
....
}
```

In your HTML, import the helper

```
@import helper._
```

and try

```
 @select(
     myForm("myDropdownId"),
     options = options(ComboboxOpts.myCustomOptions),
     '_label -> "This is my dropdown label",
     '_showConstraints -> false
 )
```

Another way to do it is to define a custom form field. See this [link](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers)

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit(), 'id -> "myForm") {
    <select>
        <option>This is option 1</option>
        <option>This is option 2</option>
        <option>This is option 3</option>
    </select>
}
```

Please be sure to do an extensive Google search before you ask these questions. I am sure there are tutorials and or the same question that has been already been asked

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

```
Use String in List[String] (in your html) List<String> in your java file.
Or if you want both value and text of drop down to be different like :

    <option value="1">One</option>

Use Map<String, String> instead of List<String> and pass it to @select

    Java file:
    Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
        options.put("1", "One");
        options.put("2", "Two");
    return ok(views.html.name.render(options, NameForm));

    Html:
    @(name: Map<String, String>,NameForm: Form[Name])
```